# I am trying to get the string between hyphen (-) which is before (+) upto next colon (:)

Tags: sql-server, substring

```
03/02/2020, 7:41 pm - +91 9999999999: At 7:10;
03/02/2020, 7:41 pm - + abcd : At 7:10;
```

**Note:** The string in between `-` and `:` is not of same length in each record. Please, help me with a solution applicable in such case.

Comment: actually after ; that is the next record. so i want (- +91 9999999999: ) or whatever is between - and : in each record like (- abcd:) which is in next record.thanks for u r input @Akina

Comment: yes there is a default space of 1 in between - and +

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT txt, 
       SUBSTRING(txt, CHARINDEX('-', txt), CHARINDEX(':', txt, CHARINDEX('-', txt)) - CHARINDEX('-', txt))
FROM test
```

or

```
SELECT txt, 
       SUBSTRING(txt, CHARINDEX('- +', txt), CHARINDEX(':', txt, CHARINDEX('- +', txt)) - CHARINDEX('- +', txt))
FROM test
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=82709d94af7b420cef395aa0952fbf70)

Comment: Thank u so much @Akina it worked.

Comment: @vinayak If the answer is correct, then please mark it as so - it might help others with the same issue in the future!